# SerialPort.ReadExisting() method not returns a string correctly at some times

Tags: c#, serial-port

The SerialPort.ReadExisting method not returns my string correctly at some times.

Here is my code:

```
string Initial="";
SerialPort sp = new SerialPort { PortName = "COM3", BaudRate = 9600, Parity = Parity.None, StopBits = StopBits.One, DataBits = 8, Handshake = Handshake.None};

sp.Open();
sp.WriteLine("P");
Initial = sp.ReadExisting();  // Then Initial must be OK.

if (Initial == "OK")
{ ....}
```

But, the results saying 'O' or 'K' or 'OK'. I dont know why it's happening. How should i avoid this situation and get correct string from serial through ReadExisting() or any other method at all time.

Note: Post your answer with code will more helpful because of newbie in C#.

Comment: Do focus on the word "Existing".  You only get the characters that exist.  Serial ports are slow so having only "O" exist in the receive buffer and the "K" not yet received is entirely normal.  High odds that you only need sp.ReadLine() to solve your problem.

Comment: As Hans said many things can go wrong or slow on a serial port. You should also consider to use a protocol. Something that consider the message complete only if the first and last chars are received. Put your message in <> and read what is in between them.

Comment: Without more details, it's not possible to answer this. Hans is correct that you are seeing normal behavior for the method you're calling and his guess that you could call `ReadLine()` instead is a good one (you call `WriteLine()` to send data, so maybe your protocol uses line-break characters to delimit messages). But if changing `ReadExisting()` to `ReadLine()` doesn't fix the problem, you need to edit the question to provide better details about your situation.